# Hide background behind modal angular ui-bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I created my modal in a factory.  Almost everything works the way that I want it to.  However, When I select my modal the background color does not darken behind the modal.

Angular bootstrap provides a plunker me to play with the modals.  From what I notice the background darkening seems to already be set.

I read through the docs but from what I understand backdrop is used to add increased click handling to escape the modal.

Below is my code.  It does work.  I just do not understand why the background behind the modal doesn't darken.  Any tips and insight would definitely be appreciated.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');

app.factory('ModalService', ['$modal', '$modalStack','$log',function($modal, $modalStack, $log) {
    return {
      trigger:function(selectedDrink){
        return $modal.open({
          templateUrl: 'templates/editCaffeineDrink.html',
          controller: function($scope,$modalInstance,drink,DrinkLibrary,Drink){
            $scope.drink = drink.editable ? drink : angular.copy(drink);
            console.log('drink',$scope.drink.date);

            $scope.ok = function(id){
              DrinkLibrary.updateDrink(id,$scope.drink).
                success(function(data){
                  console.log(data);
                  $modalInstance.close($scope.drink);               
                });            
            };
            $scope.cancel = function(){
              $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };
              // end of cancel
          },
          // end of controller
          size: 'sm',
          resolve: {
                // resolve the drink
              drink: function () {
                return selectedDrink;
              }
              // end of drink function
          }
              // end of resolve
        });
          // end of modal open
      }
      // trigger closure
    };
    // return closure
}]);
// end of factory
```

Comment: It's the bootstrap css that darkens the backdrop. Is it included on your page? Do you in some way override it with custom css?

Comment: I do have the link for bootstrap set up.  I just worked through my css files, but nothing was affecting the background.

Comment: Ok... because for me when the modal is opened a separate div is created with the css class "modal-backdrop" which the bootstrap css styles with background-color black and some opacity. Do you have this backdrop div?

Comment: What version of ui-bootstrap and bootstrap css are you using?

Comment: I am running version 0.13.0.   When I worked through my dev tools I did not find "modal-backdrop".  So i think this might be part of the problem.  The background comes up in dev tools when I highlight                           <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" ng-class="size ? 'modal-' + size : ''"><div class="modal-content" modal-transclude="">